# Looping lines in Python PEXPECT

Tags: python, pexpect

I have a txt file created named "commands.txt" and it contains two commands ( 2 lines)

```
sh run vlan 158   
sh run vlan 159
```

i want to run this two command in a switch but only one commands get executed.here is how my script looks like:

```
 def shvlan(device,child):  
   commandFile = open('commands.txt', 'r') 
   commands = [i for i in commandFile]  
   for command in commands:  
    child.sendline(command)  
    child.expect('.*#')  
    vlans = child.after  
    child.close()  
    print device + ' conn closed'  
    print 'sh run vlan executed'  
    print vlans  
    return vlans
```

Any suggestion why it is taking only 1st line of the .txt file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are closing the connection inside your loop. You have to move that part of code after the loop. Try something like this

```
 def shvlan(device,child):
     vlans = []
     with open('commands.txt', 'r') as commands: 
         for command in commands:  
             child.sendline(command)  
             child.expect('.*#')  
             vlans.extend(child.after.splitlines())  

     child.close()  
     print device + ' conn closed'  
     print 'sh run vlan executed' 
     print vlans  
     return vlans
```

Comment: Appericiated !!!!! multiple commands are getting executed...thanks a lot.

Comment: CAN WE SEPARATE EACH LINE BY COMMA ( ,) IN THE LIST.NOW ITS ALL COMING AS 2 ELEMENTS IN LIST:

__ SWITCH1# sh run vlan 158

__!Command: show running-config vlan 158
__!Time: Thu Jul 19 05:46:37 2018

__version 7.1(4)N1(1c)
__vlan configuration 158
__vlan 158
  __name MARKETING
  __mode fabricpath

__SWITCH1# sh run vlan 159

__!Command: show running-config vlan 159
__!Time: Thu Jul 19 05:46:42 2018

__version 7.1(4)N1(1c)
__vlan configuration 159
__vlan 159
  __name SALES
  __mode fabricpath

Comment: each line starts with "__ " is a new line . i added " __ " to mark as a new line as there was no option to copy/paste the exact format here .

Comment: so how to separate each line of output of the command  by a comma (,) and put that in vlans [ ]

Comment: pls suggest ,any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by `separate each line of output of the command by a comma`. For example `!Command: show running-config vlan 158` is a line from the output. How would you like to split?

Comment: @Sunitha-------like
['SWITCH1# sh run vlan 158','Command: show running-config vlan 158','!Time: Thu Jul 19 05:46:37 2018'.'version 7.1(4)N1(1c)','vlan configuration 158','vlan 158','name MARKETING','mode fabricpath','SWITCH1# sh run vlan 159 ','!Command: show running-config vlan 159','!Time: Thu Jul 19 05:46:42 2018','version 7.1(4)N1(1c)','vlan configuration 159','vlan 159','name SALES','mode fabricpath']

Comment: Got it. So you want a list of lines. I have updated my answer to add lines to the vlans list by saying `vlans.extend(child.after.splitlines())`. Can you check if it works for you

Comment: this works just the way i was looking for...you r brilliant ..Thanks a lot

Comment: How to do that ? is there any such option avl ? i am new to this forum  , have no idea ..

Comment: i am trying the get the difference of the two list. List 1 has " vlan 159 " and List 2 has " vlan 159 " " name SALES " " mode fabricpath" . So can i get the output ( diff ) as   "name SALES" " mode fabricpath"  two different subsets of vlan 159 . its difficult here to show the format .i have raised a new question .Please refer my question "List Comparison in Python with Diff as output ".Thanks

Comment: Pls suggest , any idea ?

Comment: the two list are :
a = [' sh run vlan 158', '', '', '', '!Command: show running-config vlan 158', '!Time: Thu Jul 19 12:35:57 2018', '', 'version 7.1(4)N1(1c)', 'vlan configuration 158', 'vlan 158', '  name MARKETING', '  mode fabricpath', '', '', 'SWITCH-TEST1# ', '', '', 'SWITCH-TEST1#', ' sh run vlan 159', '', '', '', '!Command: show running-config vlan 159', '!Time: Thu Jul 19 12:35:57 2018', '', 'version 7.1(4)N1(1c)', 'vlan configuration 159', 'vlan 159','', '', 'SWITCH-TEST1# ', '', '', 'SWITCH-TEST1#']

Comment: b = [' sh run vlan 158', '', '', '', '!Command: show running-config vlan 158', '!Time: Thu Jul 19 12:36:00 2018', '', 'version 7.1(4)N1(1c)', 'vlan configuration 158', 'vlan 158', '  name MARKETING', '  mode fabricpath', '', '', 'SWITCH-TEST2# ', '', '', 'SWITCH-TEST2#', ' sh run vlan 159', '', '', '', '!Command: show running-config vlan 159', '!Time: Thu Jul 19 12:36:00 2018', '', 'version 7.1(4)N1(1c)', 'vlan configuration 159', 'vlan 159', '  name SALES', '  mode fabricpath', '', '', 'SWITCH-TEST2# ', '', '', 'SWITCH-TEST2#']

Comment: can we conver that into dict and out it in vlan [] and then compare ?

Comment: pls help me in getting the raw output through the above function